# Handling login logout with Facebook SDK in iOs

Tags: ios, authentication, logic, token, logout

I am trying to create some login - logout logic with the latest Facebook SDK 4.01 and Swift. What i am trying to achieve is that when the user at first authorized the app and he log out to not redirect him again to authorization web view if he has his credentials in the settings. I am using the following code to test if an account exists:

```
func accounts() {
    var accountStore = ACAccountStore()
    var accountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(
        ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook)

    var accountsArray =
    accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(accountType)

    if accountsArray.count > 0 {
        var facebookAccount = accountsArray[0] as ACAccount
        self.returnUserData()
    }
}
```

This code gives me back the user token if a user exists on the settings of the phone. Then i call the following code:

```
func returnUserData() {
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: self.parameters )
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else {
            println("fetched user: \(result)")
        }
    })
}
```

And i get the following error: **access token must be used to query information about the current user**.
I would appreciate any suggestion or explanation on how to implement it correct.